# Ambiguous name lookup with C++20 using-enum-declaration

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, name-lookup, using-declaration

Consider following code snippet with C++20 [*using-enum-declaration*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Using-enum-declaration):

```
namespace A { enum A {}; };

using namespace A;
using enum A;
```

gcc-trunk [**rejects**](https://godbolt.org/z/j9GzTKxc4) it with:

```
<source>:4:12: error: reference to 'A' is ambiguous
    4 | using enum A;
      |            ^
<source>:1:20: note: candidates are: 'enum A::A'
    1 | namespace A { enum A {}; };
      |                    ^
<source>:1:11: note:                 'namespace A { }'
    1 | namespace A { enum A {}; };
      |           ^
<source>:4:12: error: 'A' has not been declared
    4 | using enum A;
      |            ^
```

However, msvc **accepts** it. Interestingly, if I add a namespace qualifier for `enum A`:

```
namespace A { enum A {}; };

using namespace A;
using enum A::A;
```

gcc **accepts** it this time, but msvc [**rejects**](https://godbolt.org/z/Kz6zMzdob) it with:

```
<source>(4): error C2872: 'A': ambiguous symbol
<source>(1): note: could be 'A'
<source>(1): note: or       'A::A'
```

Which compiler is right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gcc is wrong here (submitted [100'084](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100084)).

The grammar for `using enum A;` is from [[enum.udecl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/enum.udecl):

> *using-enum-declaration*:
>
> `using` *elaborated-enum-specifier* `;`

Lookup for such a thing is defined in [[basic.lookup.elab]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.elab):

> If the *class-key* or `enum` keyword in an *elaborated-type-specifier* is followed by an *identifier* that is not followed by ​`::`​, lookup for the *identifier* is type-only ([basic.lookup.general]).

An *elaborated-enum-specifier* is one kind of *elaborated-type-specifier*, so we do type-only lookup. Which is defined as, in [[basic.lookup.general]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.general#4):

> However, if a lookup is *type-only*, only declarations of types and templates whose specializations are types are considered; furthermore, if declarations of a *typedef-name* and of the type to which it refers are found, the declaration of the typedef-name is discarded instead of the type declaration.

This means that when we look up `A`, while we find both the `enum A` and the `namespace A`, because our lookup is type-only we only consider the former and not the latter. As a result, we only have a single candidate and that's the one our lookup finds. There is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

MSVC is correct here.  The first case is a type-only lookup (as it’s considered an elaborated type specifier), so it ignores the namespace and finds the enumeration via the *using-directive*.  In the second case, the following `::` allows namespaces to be found, so it’s ambiguous.

Comment: Wait the second case is _supposed_ to be ambiguous? I love this language. I thought it was so "obvious" that MSVC was wrong for the second one that I didn't even write that...

Comment: @Barry gcc seems to have this [issue](https://godbolt.org/z/aqzWb9K5Y) a long time ago.

Comment: @Barry: You can do qualified lookup into any enumeration.  The fact that you can’t possibly find there an entity that would be a valid subject for an *elaborated-type-specifier* isn’t considered, as per usual.